# How to start with database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, winforms

i have just started using visual studio 2008.I am working on c#.

I want to add SQL database particularly LOCAL database (.sdf) to my project and want to use queries  which will save data in database and fetch some data from database and which will display and will perform different function.

So, if any body can give me any small tutorial or link  that what are various types of databases i can use along with visual studio and and how will i  be able  to use it.

Any general tutorial will do.

Thanks a lot.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use .sdf databases. 
I've worked with it but it was confusing. I was not able to use WHERE statements....

Use [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) instead.

That is THE Solution.

Download SQLite [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/)
Another [tutorial](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/20f7912e-6fa7-40eb-b31b-b6f46d4f2c6a/get-started-with-sqlite-a.aspx)

Comment: My reputation was too low for more than one link. After the votes my reputation was high enough for more links. Thank you for voting..

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the use of SQLite

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Gergen was unable to perform where statements. One issue I had with Compact edition was that I couldn't create stored procs or views. I don't have much experience with SQL Lite, so I can't give an opinion on that.

If you are doing web based stuff (i.e., asp.net), I found the following series a good introduction to database stuff: [Data Access Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data)

As for what database to use, as long as there's a provider for it, working with it via ADO.NET (or entity framework, or whatever) should be similar. If you are just starting, I'd probably recommend staying with the Compact Edition since most examples/tutorials you'll see will involved SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

For simple Local SQL database stores, there are quite a few solutions.  A [good full comparison can be found on from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems)

**[SQL Express 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/)**

Out of process, runs as a windows service, supports stored procedures and views and does pretty much everything SQL standard does with few limitations.  50MB install.

Ideal for anything but large SQL deployments.

[Loads of how to guides for SQL Express](http://www.msdev.com/Directory/SeriesDescription.aspx?CourseId=124)

**[SQL Compact Edition 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) (.sdf files)**

In process, the code for accessing the database runs within the same process as your application.  Ideal for embedded systems (point of sale, ATM, in-car systems etc...).  Microsoft's equivilent to [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  Very small install (easy to deploy with app).

[Getting started guide for SQL Compact Edition](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/22/getting-started-with-sql-server-compact-edition/) and a [load of HowTos to get you going](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb219480.aspx)

**[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)**

The non-Microsoft answer to an in process database.  Pretty much the same functionality as SQL Compact Edition apart from it's a smaller install (300kb for SQLite vs. 2MB for SQL Compact edition), it supports larger database files (32TB for SQLite vs. 4GB for SQL Compact edition).

[SQLite getting started article](http://www.ivankristianto.com/software-development/visual-studio-net/howto-use-sqlite-ado-net-with-c/943/)

Answer (score 0):

[Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 from Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 and 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440724%28VS.90%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've never built anything using SQL Lite so I can't say much for it. I have, however, built several commercial applications using Compact Edition and haven't had any serious issues.

You can't batch commands with CE and the syntax is the same as Sql Server (with many missing features, but the most commonly used features are there and I've never had a problem without a work around of some sort).

I've really only used it as an "offline" database in an application for a company that dispatches repair technicians. The applications run on netbooks and download their data from a MySql database whenever mobile connectivity is available so they still have access to their work when they have no mobile coverage.

Due to it being so similar to SQL Server, Compact Edition would probably be an easier starting point. Since you're using a local database file you probably won't hit the 4GB limit (with very little pruning my mobile databases rarely exceed 20MB) - and if you ARE hitting that limit you may want to consider using a service based database (like Express) instead.